# Doubt in the proof of Blichfeldt's Theorem given in Wiki

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we are drawing some patches in a paper of size $1\times 1$. In the end, we discover that the sum of the area of all the patches is $>n$. Prove that there must exist at-least one point such that it lies in at-least $n+1$ of the patches.

This was a part in the proof of [Blitchfeldt Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blichfeldt%27s_theorem). The proof given in the link does not really seem convincing to me. The idea of contributions of points towards the area doesn't seem rigorous or at-least needs more justification in my opinion. So I was trying a "set-theoretic" approach, but could not get far.

**Progress:** When $n=1$, if no two patches have a area in common, then they all lie inside a square of area 1 and are disjoint, hence their total area can not exceed $1$. I could also show it for the case $n=2$. But could not for $n>2$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine painting each patch with an $\epsilon$ thick layer of paint. When a point is painted twice, the paint stacks in thickness. The total volume of paint is $\epsilon$ times the sum of the areas of the patches, so the volume is more than $\epsilon n$.

If you suppose by way of contradiction that no point lies in $n+1$ patches, then the maximum thickness of paint would be $n\cdot \epsilon$, so all of the paint would fit inside a $1\times 1\times (\epsilon n)$ box. This would mean the volume is also at most $\epsilon n$, which is a contradiction.

All of this can be formulated rigorously.